# Стоит ли в андроид использовать csv? или лучше sqlite?

Tags: android

Стоит ли в андроид использовать csv? или лучше sqlite?

У меня есть таблица в excel. Я думаю стоит ли использовать csv или лучше конвертить ее в sqlite?

Comment: А чем вам не нравится использование БД? Скорость работы с ней выше,  надежнее и так далее. По каким причинами вы используете csv?

Comment: @pavel, просто мне изначально высылают csv. А чтобы из csv сделать db. Мне приходиться вручную использовать SqliteBrowser.

В инете видел ReadCSV или SuperCSV. Для прямого чтения. Вот и думал. Что да как лучше.

Просто интеретсно как профи программисты поступаю в таких случаях

Comment: Я бы советовал использовать ORM. (Лучше всего - realm). Количество шаблонного кода сократится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё зависит от того что вы собираетесь с данными делать, если нужна возможность запрашивать выборку из таблицы, часто читать данные или обновлять отдельные строки/столбцы таблицы, то имеет смысл использовать SQLite. Если же вам нужно просто изредка прочитать всю таблицу в какой-нибудь список никак его при запросе не фильтруя и обновлять вы будете только всю таблицу целиком, то заморачиваться с использованием БД смысла нет.